# Why can independent random variables have their probability density functions written as a product?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

If $X$ and $Y$ are two *independent* random variables: Then why is it true that

$$\rho (x,y)=\rho_x(x)\times\rho_y(y)$$

I just don't understand if the variables are independent; what justifies their probability densities to be written as a product?

I can see from the vote counts that people want to close this question as it appears unclear; and on reflection I too agree that it is a little unclear.

So in response to the comments below, I acknowledge that it can't be proved, all I am looking for here is a little motivation for the formula. I have looked on-line and they just state the formula without logic or reasoning (which is not helpful).

Distribution theory is not my strong point so I am somewhat unfamiliar with this formula; If someone could simply post a link that explains it a bit more intuitively (or give an intuitive answer) I would be most grateful.

Comment: It is the definition of independence of random variables that the density of the joint distribution can be written as such a product.

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your reply, I don't normally accept something is the case just by definition. Can you prove this definition?

Comment: Definitions cannot be proven. They merely introduce some terminology. In this case, if random variables $X$ and $Y$ happen to have the property that $\rho(x,y)=\rho_x(x)\rho_y(y)$, then we say that they are independent. The definition doesn't do anything other than introducing a new word. With that said, one can argue that this particular new word signifies a property that makes intuitive sense to human beings, and one can then try to justify that the given definition merges well with our intuition.

Comment: @How Okay, very well; thanks for explaining

Comment: @ConradTurner No, that is **not** the usual definition of independence of random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition I'm familiar with is: random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if for all real numbers $a, b$,
$$ \mathbb P(X \le a, Y \le b) = \mathbb P(X \le a) \mathbb P(Y \le b)$$

EDIT:

In case $X$ and $Y$ have densities, 
$$ \mathbb P(X \le a) \mathbb P(Y \le b) = \int_{-\infty}^a dx\; f_X(x)
\int_{-\infty}^b dy\; f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^a dx \int_{-\infty}^b dy\; f_X(x) f_Y(y) $$
which says that $f_X(x) f_Y(y)$ is a joint density for $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please elaborate on the part you said about differentiating a density function? I didn't know that differentiating had any meaning with probability distributions.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful, I have just one further question: Why is it that when you differentiate a probability distribution the result is a probability density?

Comment: By definition, a probability density for random variable $X$ is a function $f$ such that $F(a) = \mathbb P(X \le a) = \int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\; dx$.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,  we have $f(a) = F'(a)$ on any interval where $f$ is continuous.